# Image below action bar and for different screen sizes

Tags: android, image, layout, android-actionbar

any idea how can i implement this small spike under action bar and it can be in the same place for different screen sizes?

[image]

Comment: it looks like something that points a View , so why don't you align it to that View?

Comment: but in different screen sizes it will be misaligned, doesn't?

Comment: No, if you'll create your XML correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a .png for different resolutions.

Otherwise you can build a triangle using a xml file.
Something like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item >
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="45"
                android:toDegrees="45"
                android:pivotX="135%"
                android:pivotY="15%" >
                <shape
                    android:shape="rectangle"  >
                    <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:width="XXdp"/>
                    <solid
                        android:color="@color/mycolor"  />
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Comment: you mean i have insert an image at the top of the screen and set this as a background?

Comment: thanks for the idea, this worked.. `android:pivotX="135%" android:pivotY="15%"`, but no i have the shadow below actionBar problem,